# Php query 2 mysql tables with dates BETWEEN and multiple clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables named
Receipts and Materials_Receipts_Markup

I am needing to query these mysql tables between specific user input dates from a form and as well as a condition that will search for all dates from a specific user (techID) from both tables. I having a tough go at it so far and don't think I am even close. Here's what I have so far

```
"SELECT Receipts.TechID, Receipts.TotalPrice, Receipts.TotalProfit,
Receipts.Date, Materials_Receipts_Markup.Markup, 
Materials_Receipts_Markup.DateOfReceipt,
Materials_Receipts_Markup.TechID".

"FROM Receipts, Materials_Receipts_Markup".

"WHERE Receipts.Date BETWEEN '$newStartDate' AND '$newEndDate' AND WHERE
Materials_Receipts_Markup.DateOfReceipt BETWEEN '$newStartDate' AND
'$newEndDate'".

"AND Receipts.TechID AND Materials_Receipts_Markup.TechID ='$FormTechID' ";
```

`$newStartDate` and `$newEndDate` are dates such as 2019-06-23

my sql skills aren't up to par yet for something this complicated. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables? It seems to be TechID, but you do not specify anything which allows the join of the two tables. Is there a relationship between a Receipt and a Markup? Does a receipt have to have a Markup?

Comment: TechID does have a relationship between the 2 tables as well as the dates being search for in the tables/fields Receipts.Date and Materials_Receipts_Markup.DateOfReceipt

Comment: I think the query is almost corect. You only have to change the "WHERE" query to just only once instead of two. And in the last clause, you could change `TechID ='$FormTechID'` to `Receipts.TechID ='$FormTechID'` to prevent ambiguous `TechID` column select

Comment: The techID needs to be searched from both tables `Receipts.TechID` and `Materials_Receipts_Markup.TechID` and I'm trying to pull only the recs from specific dates from both tables. Wouldnt this need WHERE for both `Materials_Receipts_Markup.DateOfReceipt` and `Receipts.Date` tables/fields?

Comment: Then add another clause like `AND Materials_Receipts_Markup.TechID=Receipts.TechID`

Comment: It appears that, except for being entered by the same TechID and being in the same date range, there is no logical connection between the two tables. If what you are trying to do is retrieve all the entries by TechID for a given period from two independent tables, then you want to create a UNION.

Comment: @JacalarRick that is EXACTLY what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use an `OR` to search each table separated, and get both `TechID` using `=` operator like :

```sql
WHERE 
(
    (Receipts.Date BETWEEN '$newStartDate' AND '$newEndDate') 
    OR
    (Materials_Receipts_Markup.DateOfReceipt BETWEEN '$newStartDate' AND '$newEndDate') 
)
AND Receipts.TechID = Materials_Receipts_Markup.TechID AND Receipts.TechID ='$FormTechID'
```

Comment: Using OR would not get me results from both tables

Comment: It as well returns an error of `Error: Unknown table 'Receipts' in field list`

Comment: How do you write the final query?

Comment: I just ended up doing 2 separate queries as I couldn't get anything else to work

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is another linking field between the two tables, there does not seem to be any logical connection between them, other than the data is entered by the same TechID.   Instead of a JOIN, you may need a UNION instead

```
  select r.techid as tech, r.date as date, r.totalprice as price, r.totalprofit as profit, null as markup  
    from receipts r 
    where r.TechID = 'FormTechID' and r.date between '$newStartDate' AND '$newEndDate'

  UNION

  select mrm.TechID as tech, mrm.DateOfReceipt as date, null as price, null as profit,   mrm.markup as markup
    from Materials_Receipts_Markup mrm
    where mrm.TechID = '$FormTechID' and mrm.DateOfReceipt between '$newStartDate' AND '$newEndDate'
```

If there is some other field (such as ReceiptID), then you need to join your tables on that.